# Spring boot: resolve property files when using more than one profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot

im using spring boot. It has this nice feature of automatically finding property files when using profile, so if I add

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

to application.properties it also finds `application-local.properties` file. Is there any way to use the same feature when more than one profile is specified? application-local-dk.properties doesnt work. I want to have separated files for different environment-locale pairs.
so:

```
application-local-dk.properties
application-local-se.properties...
application-test-dk.properties
application-test-se.properties
application-prod-dk.properties...
```

Comment: Why do you want different properties based on locale?

Comment: I use different mongo databases / collections for each locale. Dont want to squeeze it in one file for each env. This question is part of idea to run separate applications for different locales by using profiles instead of having all locale variations in one context. There is no routing data source for mongo template which I could use so im trying different options before looking deeper in mongodb factory or some similar class.

Comment: You want the locale to be resolved at runtime somehow? I don't think that's possible. You can of course just set `spring.profiles.active=local-dk`, is that not an option for you?

Comment: no, probably apache server would point to different ports for different domains on tomcat machine, where more than one app would be started. So each locale version would be served on different port/spring profile/properties file. I wonder if it would be easier and cleaner for code to have it like this instead creating some proxies in front of services and repositories.